# Importing multiple correlated XSD on LiquidXML

Tags: liquid-xml

I have multiple correlated XSDs that needs to be uploaded in order to create a large library, but I haven't had any option to do so on the interface. The option to select XSD is only limited to one file.

Is there a way to go around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a 'Super Schema' which will include or import all of your top level schema.

Please see the knowledge base article:
[Liquid XML Data Binder - Super Schema](http://support.liquid-technologies.com/kb/a80/super-schema.aspx)